# Crear un trigger para ejecutarlo antes de insert

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Quiero hacer un Trigger en MySQL que haga lo siguiente:

Antecedente: tengo una tabla llamada x con 3 columnas: id (int), nombre(varchar) y estado(enum).
Sólo puede existir 1 registro con el estado Si (columna tipo enum; Si , No)

1. Al momento de insertar un registro en la tabla x, el Trigger busque dentro de la tabla x si ya existe un registro con estado Si y entonces lo cambie a No.

Tengo actualmente esto:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER test BEFORE INSERT ON x
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

/*
    Aquí ya no se como decirle que busque
    a los que están en estatus Si
    y los cambie por No
*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un trigger no puede modificar la misma tabla a la que está vinculado.

La solución más simple que se me ocurre es escribir un procedimiento para insertar valores que haga la actualización necesaria:

```
create table x (
  id int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  nombre varchar(50),
  estado enum('Si','No')
);

delimiter //
create procedure insertaEnX(n varchar(50), e char(2))
begin
  if e = 'Si' then
    update x
      set estado = 'No';
  end if;
  insert into x(nombre, estado) values(n, e);
end //
delimiter ;
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
call insertaEnX('Nombre 1', 'Si');
select * from x;
    | id |   nombre | estado |
    |----|----------|--------|
    |  1 | Nombre 1 |     Si |

call insertaEnX('Nombre 2', 'No');
select * from x;
    | id |   nombre | estado |
    |----|----------|--------|
    |  1 | Nombre 1 |     Si |
    |  2 | Nombre 2 |     No |

call insertaEnX('Nombre 3', 'Si');
select * from x;
    | id |   nombre | estado |
    |----|----------|--------|
    |  1 | Nombre 1 |     No |
    |  2 | Nombre 2 |     No |
    |  3 | Nombre 3 |     Si |
```